# How to find which lines of code cause package dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I built a package with many long R scripts. [I can find the dependencies of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-dependency-graph.html) but it would be very helpful to know which files and which lines are using functions for a particular package.

E.g. My package depends on `lubridate` but it would be better to know that I use lubridate functions in lines x,y,z of scripts alpha.R and beta.R

Does anyone know if there is any package doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodeDepends package may be of use to you:

From the [CRAN Index page](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/CodeDepends/index.html):

> CodeDepends: Analysis of R Code for Reproducible Research and Code
>   Comprehension
>
> Tools for analyzing R expressions or blocks of code and determining
>   the dependencies between them. It focuses on R scripts, but can be
>   used on the bodies of functions. There are many facilities including
>   the ability to summarize or get a high-level view of code, determining
>   dependencies between variables, code improvement suggestions.

From the [Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CodeDepends/vignettes/intro.html):

> The CodeDepends package provides a flexible framework for statically analyzing R code (i.e., without evaluating it). It also contains higher-level functionality for: detecting dependencies between R code blocks or expressions, “tree-shaking” (pruning a script down to only the expressions necessary to evaluate a given expression), plotting variable usage timelines, and more.

Also, note the `makeCallGraph` function can "create call graphs for functions or entire packages"